# Add rectangle to Google Maps using dimensions not LatLon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon, dimensions

I have a map on a webpage and I'd like to be able to add a rectangle of a specific size. Currently done as follows.

```
var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        bounds: {
            north: 33.685,
            south: 33.671,
            east: -116.224,
            west: -116.251
        }
    });
```

Is it possible to add a rectangle to Google Maps using the dimensions rather than the co-ordinates?

For example, say I want to draw a rectangle 250ft high x 600ft wide on a map?

Thanks

Comment: Yes and no.  You need to calculate the coordinates from the dimensions (and a location point, either the center or a known vertex).  You can do that with the geometry library.

Comment: ok thanks - had wondered if had to do the maths rather than a built in option - if you can add as an answer i'll accept it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the coordinates from the dimensions (and a location point, either the center or a known vertex). You can do that with the geometry library.

```
// 250ft high x 600ft wide
// 1 ft = 0.3048 meters
var rectBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(
    google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(map.getCenter(), 250*0.3048, 180).lat(), // south
    google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(map.getCenter(), 600*0.3048, 270).lng()), // west
  map.getCenter() /* NE */);
var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
map: map,
bounds: rectBounds
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9rmzuyL9/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  // 250ft high x 600ft wide
  // 1 ft = 0.3048 meters
  var rectBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(
      google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(map.getCenter(), 250 * 0.3048, 180).lat(), // south
      google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(map.getCenter(), 600 * 0.3048, 270).lng()), // west
    map.getCenter() /* NE */ );
  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: rectBounds
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```